# Img in floating container not clickable in Explorer

Tags: image, click, css-float, anchor, explorer

I have an anchor element with in it a div "imgbox" containing an image and a caption, and a div "textbox" containing some text.

Now when I float the div.imgbox, the img element inside is no longer clickable; the caption and the text in the div.textbox is. This only happens in Internet Explorer; all other browsers work just fine.

Does anyone know what's causing this (and how to solve it)? Thanks!

here's the css and html I'm using:

```
<style>
    .wrap a {
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;/* makes this a wrap around floats */
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .imgbox {
        float: left;
    }
    .textbox {
        overflow: hidden;/* positions the div next to the float */
    }
</style>

<div class="wrap">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="imgbox">
            <img src="http://jaron.nl/misc/dummy.gif" width="80" height="45" alt="" />
            caption text is clickable
        </div>
        <div class="textbox">
            some text here
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Block element in div in between the img and a link tag .

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Unfortunately, changing the div to a span does not make a difference... Also, as far as I know, putting block-level elements within an anchor should not affect anything, it's just not valid in html4 (but it is in html5)